# Continuidad de funciones

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Ayuda para la demostración o un contra ejemplo del siguiente enunciado:

Si $(f∘r)(t)$ es continua $∀r$ continua y $r(t_{0})=x_{0}$,entonces $f$ es continua.
Con $r$ y $x_{0}$vectores

Donde $r$ es una trayectoria y $f$ es una función 
En caso de un contra ejemplo favor específicar el porque y justificarlo

Se me ha ocurrido proceder por contradicción y llegar a un absurdo por el cuál lleguemos a que $f$ tiene que ser continua

Comment: Por favor aprende cómo escribir expresiones de matemáticas, como [aquí](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656007/example-of-a-function-that-is-not-continuous-at-0-0-but-continuous-when-res

Comment: Please provide an English translation of your question.